# How to see what SQL statements are executed when using SQL Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Express so I don't have access to SQL Profiler tools. Is there something I can use to see what statements are being executed while running an ASP.NET MVC application (live or in debug, either is fine).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Anjlab` it works with SQL Express http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler

Comment: the download links in your anjlab link take me to this site: http://www.datawizard.com/

Comment: the links to download on your anjlab link take me here: http://www.datawizard.com/ where you can either use the trial or buy?

Comment: @BBauer42 Very strange!!! don't click the link and try to copy and past the url in your navigator, if it still does not work a simple search on google will give you the correct link

Comment: I was able to install the sql profiler tool as we have a full license of SQL at my company.